# python pyparsing scanString - wrong start/end location

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm trying to find the start and end location of a typical token in a text with the scanString function.

```
text = """ 
    P: INT;
    timer2.et == 3423
    Q   :  INT ;
    TIME1: TIME;
    TIME2: TIME;
    TIMER_Q3 : BOOL;
    WECHSEL : BOOL;
    m : BOOL;
    timer.q = 4
"""
```

From this text I want to find the location of the XXX.et and the XXX.q tokens:

```
import pyparsing as pp

TK_TIMER_Q_ET = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_") + (pp.Literal(".q")  | pp.Literal(".et"))

t_end = []
t_match = []
t_start = []
for match, start, end in TK_TIMER_Q_ET.scanString(text):
    t_match.append(match)
    t_start.append(start)
    t_end.append(end)

i = len(t_match) - 1
k = 0
while k <= i:
    print("t_end=", t_end[k])
    print("t_start=", t_start[k])
    print("t_match=", t_match[k])
    print("match=", text[t_start[k]:t_end[k]])
    k += 1
```

As an output I expect "timer2.et" and "timer.q" when I print "match=...", but I get:

```
t_end= 35
t_start= 26
t_match= ['timer2', '.et']
match= 423
    Q   
t_end= 189
t_start= 182
t_match= ['timer', '.q']
match=
```

Would be awesome if somebody could help me with that issue!

Comment: Are there tabs in your input string? Pyparsing implicitly calls str.expandtabs before running its parse/scan methods. Before dumping out your results, try `text = text.expandtabs()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, thats the key!

Comment: My mistake - I was looking at the location numbers and didn't fully read that you wanted to get the strings as strings, not as lists - @sophros was on the right track, and the comments should get you the rest of the way there

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the grouping of the characters to make one identifier. Try changing the code the following way:

```
K_TIMER_Q_ET = pp.Group(pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_") + (pp.Literal(".q")  | pp.Literal(".et")))
```

Works for me:

```
('t_end=', 27)
('t_start=', 18)
('t_match=', ([(['timer2', '.et'], {})], {}))
('match=', 'timer2.et')
('t_end=', 153)
('t_start=', 146)
('t_match=', ([(['timer', '.q'], {})], {}))
('match=', 'timer.q')
```

Comment: Using `pp.Combine`  instead of `pp.Group` will re-concatentate these identifiers into single strings.

Comment: My impression was that the issue is in the indices but indeed you are right about the `parseResult` - `Combine` will make one string per each match.

Comment: Some people will define such a term using `pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_.')`, which is incorrect, since this will match just plain "." or "..." or "3.14" or "12345". What is desired is a qualified name consisting of valid identifiers with '.' separators, all returned as a single string. Most robust pyparsing expression would be `pp.Combine(pp.delimitedList(pp.Word(pp.alphas+"_", pp.alphanums+"_"), delim="."))` - or using the predefined identifier from pyparsing_common: `pp.Combine(pp.delimitedList(pp.pyparsing_common.identifier, delim="."))`.